# Launching rails server with c9. not working. Getting missing argument -p

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cloud9-ide

I am launching rails server using rails -v 4.2.0 with the following code...
    "rails server -b $IP -p $port" and getting the following error.

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:12:in `parse!': missing argument: -p (OptionParser::MissingArgument)

Can someone please explain the missing argument and how to fix it?
Thks

Comment: What is the output of `echo $port`?

Answer (score 1):

Try `rails s -b $IP -p $PORT`.  Case is important.  Bonus for you - you can use *s* as a shortcut for *server*.

Answer (score 0):

I get the haarcascade_frontalface_deflult.xml file from cPanel the file are present there but it cannot detect the face its working locally fine but when I upload it on cPanel it did not detect faces properly

```
 face_detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/khblpkn3ru9o/public_html/media/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
```

i also try this

```
cv2.CascadeClassifier('http://theangrynerds.com/media/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
```

you can check file http://www.theangrynerds.com/media/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml

my complete module code here

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def imgDelete(request,id):
    # if request.method== 'POST':
    Image.objects.filter(name=id).delete()
    FaceName.objects.filter(name = id).delete()
    allimages = FaceName.objects.filter(User=request.user)
    # for p in allPdf:
        # print("http://127.0.0.1:8000/"+p.thumbnail)
    
    context={
        'allimg' : allimages
    }    
    return render(request, 'Application/imagess.html',context)

def location(request):
    return render(request, 'Application/location.html')

def out(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('login')


def hello(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        F_name = request.POST['name']
        user_video = request.FILES['vide']
        videoSave = videoStore.objects.create(User=User.objects.get(id=request.user.pk) , videoFile = user_video)
        get_path_video = videoStore.objects.get(pk = videoSave.pk)
        accurate_path = "http://theangrynerds.com/media/" + str(get_path_video.videoFile)

        faceCount = FaceName.objects.all().count()
        face_id = faceCount + 1
        count =0
        video = cv2.VideoCapture(accurate_path)
        # Detect object in video stream using Haarcascade Frontal Face
        
        face_detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/khblpkn3ru9o/public_html/media/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
        while True:
                # Capture video frame
            cc, image_frame = video.read()
            
            if cc == False:
                break
            # Convert frame to grayscale
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            
            # Detect frames of different sizes, list of faces rectangles
            faces = face_detector.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
            # Loops for each faces
            for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
                # Crop the image frame into rectangle
                FaceName.objects.create(User=User.objects.get(id=request.user.pk) , name = F_name , ids = face_id)
                # cv2.rectangle(image_frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255,0,0), 2)
                count += 1
                has = cv2.imwrite("/home/khblpkn3ru9o/public_html/media/" + str(request.user.username) + "." + str(face_id) + '.' + str(count) + ".jpg", gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
                
                c =  str(request.user.username)+"." + str(face_id) + '.' + str(count) + ".jpg"
                  
                Image.objects.create(User=User.objects.get(id=request.user.pk),  name=F_name , imagestore= c )
            if count == 100:
                break  
            
    FaceName.objects.create(User=User.objects.get(id=request.user.pk) , name = F_name , ids = face_id)            
    video.release() 
             
    return redirect('imagess')
```